# Tiny-MCE plugin for setting column width in table

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

We are using Tiny-MCE in our CMS, and our users would like to have the ability to change the width of a column in a table. Now, I know that from an HTML point, there is no such entity "column", but in the Moodle editor, HTMLAREA, there is a plugin that does that - allows to set a width (only in percents) to a column:

[image]

Sorry it's in Hebrew, I couldn't find a version in English...

does anyone know of a plugin to Tiny-MCE that could do that? Or have an idea how I would go about writing such a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for. It's an [enhancement of the cell dialog box](http://wiki.dt-studios.com/index.php?title=TinyMCE_Table_Plugin_Column_Range_CELL_Attribute_Update), that adds an option in the select box on the bottom:
[image]

The only thing is that you have to make sure you're in the top most cell in the column, as the JS updates only the next cells in the column, and not the previous ones. But other than that - it's just what we needed.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that what the `HTML` option is for? :)

Another choice is the `styleprops (edit Css Style)`, not sure how this works completely, but there is an option on the box tab that will let you set a width. I have removed it to avoid shenanigans!

Alternatively you could create several styles which have a width defined and then with the cursor focused on the cell by choosing the style `width20percent` the box goes 20%.

Comment: @Luke, our users aren't HTML savvy, and we cannot expect them to alter the HTML/CSS on their own. As to the styleprops - I'm not familiar with it, could you explain more please? And as to your last option - that would mean that they have to go cell by cell in the column whose width they want to change. We would like to help them avoid such tedious work :-)

Comment: `stypeprops` is the 2 As one blue one purple (?). it opens a dialog with several tabs which allow you to change various style attributes. For example the Box tab there is a width, which allows you to change the width of the box. Don't know much more am afraid, am fairly new to MCE

Comment: Thank for the explanation, @Luke! But still that doesn't give me what I want - it works per cell, just like the "Table cell properties", where I need something that works per column. And I agree with you that it's too open to shenanigans...

Comment: @Lea, Im not seeing the problem you are? The appication of a width on one cell will affect the entire column, in the same table.

Comment: @Luke - only if you're making the cell wider (because a column's width is as wide as the widest cell in it). But if you want to make a column narrower, you need to do it cell by cell.

Comment: @Lea, depending on the units, a % will expand a bit, a px will stay the same and the copy will wrap. You dont need to do it cell by cell. If you set 2 different widths in 2 different cells in the same column, only one will win. You cannot change the width of one cell without affecting the rest of the cells in the same column.

Comment: @Luke, you say "If you set 2 different widths in 2 different cells in the same column, only one will win". Which one? I think the wider one. for example: If I have a table with 2 columns and 2 rows. I set the first cell in the first column to 200px, and the second cell in the first column to 100px, the column will be 200px wide. Now, if I add another row, and set the cell in the first column to 200px, the width stays the same. Now if I want to change the column width to 100px, I'll have to update 2 cells.

Comment: @Lea, yes you right the larger one will win. I see where you are coming from now. again you are correct, if you want to make the box smaller, you need to remove all the large widths.  This could be user education? "if you want to set a column's width; only set it on the first cell of a column". If someone goes on to set a width on each subsequent cell, there is a `remove format` option, will that remove all the styles? just tested... it does, but you have to select the entire cell.

Comment: @Luke, thank you very much for your research and help. Although I found an answer myself, I am awarding you the bounty because you really tried to help me.

Answer (score 2):

@Lea Cohen: I found this plugin for TinyMCE -- http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2800315&group_id=103281&atid=738747 -- which sounds like it should do what you wish, perhaps even in a more "user friendly" way than making the user enter widths manually:

> Adds the ability to resize a tables' cell borders by dragging the mouse ..

The way I see it working is resizing the first cells acting as the "column" headings which should see subsequent cells in that column inheriting the width settings, e.g.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="300">Col 1</td>
        <td width="200">Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Width 300</td>
        <td>Width 200</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**

If that plugin doesn't work for you, you should also have a look at the *Table* plugin which seems to have options for controlling rows/cells as well: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin:table

Comment: Thank you @stealthyninja, but that's still not what I want. The first link you gave is to a feature we already have in our version of TinyMCE, and what it does is change the widths of *all* the columns in a table, but you can't control a single column. As to the Table plugin, it controls cells in rows or in whole table, but not in whole column.

Comment: `.. control a single column ..` -- to do that, you have to select all the cells in the column then right-click, select _Cell_ and then _Table cell properties_ to update the width, otherwise the cell in that column with the largest width will always trump what ever width you've set. :-/

Comment: As far as I can tell, @stealthyninja, there is no way to select all cells in column. When I try to do that, all the cells in the rows in which the column cells are, get selected too.